# Interpretation of space time Minkowski diagram

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor

How to interpret the following space-time diagram in the image.

I know how to interpret euclidean distance from Euclidean space diagram

Comment: I don't understand the question. Spacetime diagrams are diagram where one axis is the time and the other is the space. What is giving you trouble about that?

Comment: @ACuriousMind   the actual distances aren't drawn geometrically in space-time diagram.

Comment: And? That's the way it is in such diagrams, zero interval paths correspond to 45° lines. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking about the difference between distances in Euclidean and Minkowskii space. In a "Euclidean spacetime diagram" the distances $ds^2_E=c^2dt^2+dx^2$ would correspond to the lines you draw on the diagram. In Minkowskii space, the lines you draw on the diagram might correspond to particle paths, but they do not correspond to the interval $ds^2_M=-c^2dt^2+dx^2$. You can see this is true just because you can draw light paths in Minkowskii space (diagonal lines) but these have length $ds^2=0$.

This is basically just a side effect of the constancy of the speed of light. All objects move at the same speed in spacetime (so as time ticks off the $t$-axis you know where any object is by looking at it's path in a spacetime diagram), but the same is not true in space.